# 4-fold chemical compounds

Tags: coordination-compounds

I have been reading some papers and one mentioned "4-fold triethylamine based on PEG-diol end groups", "4-fold acryloyl chloride." What is the meaning of "4-fold" in those compounds? Also, can I find these chemicals for sale or must I synthesize them myself?

Comment: Can you link to some of these things you're referring to? There's not really enough context here to be able to help explain them.

Comment: Welcome to the Chemistry SE! You should take the [tour](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/tour) and, if you have any further questions about the site, visit the [help center](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help). As written, your question may get closed for not providing sufficient context. You should edit your question to include links to the articles you are referring to and maybe what you hope to do with this compound. I have found a [patent](https://www.google.com/patents/US20060073281)  that references what you are talking about. Best of luck in finding an answer!

Answer (score 1):

*Assuming* the "4-fold" *is not* referring to "use four equivalents of X per molecular function Y to obtain the intended chemical reaction", it refers more often to a specical class of star shaped polymers, called [dendrimers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dendrimer).  Commonly, around a nucleous, you have several times the same chemical group, as, for example, drawn here:

[image]

In this example, instead of a linear chain of polyethylene glycol (PEG), four branches are stitched together; the fourth example may relate the closest to your question.

Source of the picture: Zhu, *Biomaterials* **31** (2010) 4639-4656, doi: 10.1016/j.biomaterials.2010.02.044